# Trying to comment out lines in a file with instance of a word

Tags: bash, unix

This is probably another super simple question, I just can't figure it out.  I'm writing a script that needs to comment out all the lines of a file that have any instance of the word "NETWORKID".  The problem is, the code I have is putting a "#" at the beginning of all the lines of the particular file. (/etc/profile)

What I have is this:

```
grep -i "NETWORKID" /etc/profile | sed 's/^/#/'
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need grep, just used `sed:

```
sed '/NETWORKID/s/^/#/' /etc/profile
```

Answer (score 1):

Using -i(something) will update the file and create a backup with the extension, eg

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/(.*NETWORKID.*)/#\1/' /etc/profile
```

Will update your profile, and create a copy of how profile was before running the command in /etc/profile.bak